# How did Dass Jennir and Kai Hudorra know that Beyhgor Sahdett was a traitor?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In the final story arc of the *Star Wars: Dark Times* comic series, the fugitive Jedi, Dass Jennir and Kai Hudorra, meet Beyhgor Sahdett, a fellow Jedi (but now secretly a traitor serving Palpatine), who urges them to launch a high-risk strike at the Empire.

What puzzles me is how both Jedi rightly deduced that Sahdett was in fact an enemy and exposed him on the spot. How did they know Sahdett was a traitor?

Any references to tell-tale signs within the entire Dark Times series (32 issues) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The implication seems to be that they "sensed it" but I can't see anything explicit in the comics themselves.